# Sort a List<StringBuilder>

Tags: c#, list, stringbuilder

Requirement: Iterate through a sorted list of strings, adding a char at the beginning of each string, then re-sorting. This may need to be done a few thousand times. I tried using a regular List of strings but, as expected, the process was way too slow.

I was going to try a List of StringBuilders but there is no direct way to sort the list. Any workarounds come to mind?

Comment: What do you mean by "adding a char at the beginning of each string"? The same character? This is a fairly odd requirement - could you give more details and an example? What counts as "way too slow" and how many strings do you have?

Comment: In addition to what Jon Skeet said, some code or psuedo-code would be nice too.

Comment: It's a genetic analysis algorithm, and yes, many bio-related algorithms are a bit odd. The characters to be prepended are not the same (otherwise the strings would not need to be resorted). There are conceivably a few thousand strings, each of a few thousand characters, so the CPU load and memory requirements add up fast. I tested a version that used strings, and it took about 15 minutes or so.  I plan to look at the base algorithm more closely, but I'm not counting on finding a better approach.

Comment: For anyone interested, the actual algorithm is Burrows-Wheeler: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burrows-wheeler .  It's the decompression part that requires the char-prepends and numerous sorts.  Interesting algorithm--it doesn't look like it would work, but it does.

Answer (score 2):

You've stated you can't sort a Link - however, you can if you can supply your own sort comparison:

```
List<StringBuilder> strings = new List<StringBuilder>();
// ...
strings.Sort((s1, s2) => s1.ToString().CompareTo(s2.ToString()));
```

The problem here as @phoog notes, is that in order to do so it allocates a lot of extra strings and isn't very efficient. The sort he provides is better. What we can do to figure out which approach is better is supply a test. You can see the fiddle here: http://dotnetfiddle.net/Px4fys

The fiddle uses very few strings and very few iterations because it's in a fiddle and there's a memory limit. If you paste this into a console app and run in Release you'll find there's huge differences. As @phoog also suggests `LinkedList<char>` wins hands-down. `StringBuilder` is the slowest.

If we bump up the values and run in `Release` mode:

```
const int NumStrings= 1000;
const int NumIterations= 1500;
```

We'll find the results:

```
List<StringBuilder> - Elapsed Milliseconds: 27,678
List<string> - Elapsed Milliseconds: 2,932
LinkedList<char> - Elapsed Milliseconds: 912
```

EDIT 2: When I bumped both values up to 3000 and 3000

```
List<StringBuilder> - Elapsed Milliseconds: // Had to comment out - was taking several minutes
List<string> - Elapsed Milliseconds: 45,928
LinkedList<char> - Elapsed Milliseconds: 6,823
```

Comment: This requires two string allocations for each comparison.  I suspect it would be slower than the OP's original solution.

Comment: Thanks, I would normally do that myself but don't have time this evening.

Answer (score 1):

<s>The string builders will be a bit quicker than strings, but still slow, since you have to copy the entire buffer to add a character at the beginning.</s>

You can create a custom comparison method (or comparer object if you prefer) and pass it to the List.Sort method:

```
int CompareStringBuilders(StringBuilder a, StringBuilder b)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length && i < b.Length; i++)
    {
        var comparison = a[i].CompareTo(b[i]);
        if (comparison != 0)
            return comparison;
    }

    return a.Length.CompareTo(b.Length);
}
```

Invoke it like this:

```
var list = new List<StringBuilder>();
//...
list.Sort(CompareStringBuilders);
```

<s>You would probably do better to look for a different solution to your problem, however.</s>

Linked lists offer quick prepending, so how about using `LinkedList<char>`?  This might not work if you need other StringBuilder functions, of course.

StringBuilder was rewritten for .NET 4, so I've struck out my earlier comments about slow prepending of characters.  If performance is an issue, you should test to see where the problems actually lie.

Comment: `LinkedList<char>` is much better.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the `StringBuilder`s as described in Phoog's answer, but keep the strings in reverse order in the `StringBuilder` instances - this way, you can optimize the "prepending" of each new character by appending it to the end of the `StringBuilder`'s current value:

Update: with test program

```
class Program
{
    static readonly Random _rng = new Random();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int stringCount = 2500;
        int initialStringSize = 100;
        int maxRng = 4;
        int numberOfPrepends = 2500;
        int iterations = 5;

        Console.WriteLine( "String Count: {0}; # of Prepends: {1}; # of Unique Chars: {2}", stringCount, numberOfPrepends, maxRng );

        var startingStrings = new List<string>();

        for( int i = 0; i < stringCount; ++i )
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder( initialStringSize );

            for( int j = 0; j < initialStringSize; ++j )
            {
                sb.Append( _rng.Next( 0, maxRng ) );
            }

            startingStrings.Add( sb.ToString() );
        }

        for( int i = 0; i < iterations; ++i )
        {
            TestUsingStringBuilderAppendWithReversedStrings( startingStrings, maxRng, numberOfPrepends );
            TestUsingStringBuilderPrepend( startingStrings, maxRng, numberOfPrepends );
        }

        var input = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void TestUsingStringBuilderAppendWithReversedStrings( IEnumerable<string> startingStrings, int maxRng, int numberOfPrepends )
    {
        var builders = new List<StringBuilder>();

        var start = DateTime.Now;

        foreach( var str in startingStrings )
        {
            builders.Add( new StringBuilder( str ).Reverse() );
        }

        for( int i = 0; i < numberOfPrepends; ++i )
        {
            foreach( var sb in builders )
            {
                sb.Append( _rng.Next( 0, maxRng ) );
            }

            builders.Sort( ( x, y ) =>
            {
                var comparison = 0;

                var xOffset = x.Length;
                var yOffset = y.Length;

                while( 0 < xOffset && 0 < yOffset && 0 == comparison )
                {
                    --xOffset;
                    --yOffset;

                    comparison = x[ xOffset ].CompareTo( y[ yOffset ] );
                }

                if( 0 != comparison )
                {
                    return comparison;
                }

                return xOffset.CompareTo( yOffset );
            } );
        }

        builders.ForEach( sb => sb.Reverse() );

        var end = DateTime.Now;

        Console.WriteLine( "StringBuilder Reverse Append - Total Milliseconds: {0}", end.Subtract( start ).TotalMilliseconds );
    }

    private static void TestUsingStringBuilderPrepend( IEnumerable<string> startingStrings, int maxRng, int numberOfPrepends )
    {
        var builders = new List<StringBuilder>();

        var start = DateTime.Now;

        foreach( var str in startingStrings )
        {
            builders.Add( new StringBuilder( str ) );
        }

        for( int i = 0; i < numberOfPrepends; ++i )
        {
            foreach( var sb in builders )
            {
                sb.Insert( 0, _rng.Next( 0, maxRng ) );
            }

            builders.Sort( ( x, y ) =>
            {
                var comparison = 0;

                for( int offset = 0; offset < x.Length && offset < y.Length && 0 == comparison; ++offset )
                {
                    comparison = x[ offset ].CompareTo( y[ offset ] );
                }

                if( 0 != comparison )
                {
                    return comparison;
                }

                return x.Length.CompareTo( y.Length );
            } );
        }

        var end = DateTime.Now;

        Console.WriteLine( "StringBulder Prepend - Total Milliseconds: {0}", end.Subtract( start ).TotalMilliseconds );
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static StringBuilder Reverse( this StringBuilder stringBuilder )
    {
        var endOffset = stringBuilder.Length - 1;

        char a;

        for( int beginOffset = 0; beginOffset < endOffset; ++beginOffset, --endOffset )
        {
            a = stringBuilder[ beginOffset ];

            stringBuilder[ beginOffset ] = stringBuilder[ endOffset ];
            stringBuilder[ endOffset ] = a;
        }

        return stringBuilder;
    }
}
```

results:

2500 strings initially at 100 characters, 2500 prepends:
[image: 2500 strings, 100-2600 chars]

Comment: Nice.  It's too bad the StringBuilder doesn't have a Reverse method; having to call `new string(s.ToString().Reverse().ToArray())` rather defeats the purpose of the StringBuilder class.

Comment: not really - you only need to do it twice per string - initially and when you're done prepending/sorting.  Your algorithm requires a full string copy (even if internally in the `StringBuilder`) each time a character is prepended.  If you're prepending thousands of characters, the initial and final string reversals are insignificant

Comment: but you gave me a great idea - implement my own reverse method for stringbuilders to avoid the extra memory allocation and copies. give me a moment

Comment: I realize only twice per string is not much, but still, the point of the SB class is to manipulate your characters in a mutable buffer and have only one object allocation when you've got them in the order you want.  The Linq expression has at least four (the backwards string, the linq iterator, the array, and the forward string, plus no doubt at least one array allocated by the Reverse iterator).  It doesn't make the StringBuilder useless, but it is certainly less efficient than a StringBuilder.Reverse method would be.  Now that I think about it, though ...

Comment: ... the SB was rewritten for .NET 4, so prepending a single character probably does not in fact require copying the entire buffer as it used to in .NET 2.

Comment: should be easy enough to test

Comment: If you're feeling ambitious, try implementing 2 or 3 solutions and comparing their performance.  I've just reviewed the .NET 4 StringBuilder code and I suspect that trying to second-guess its performance would actually make things worse.  It's constructed as a linked list of "chunks," so it should in fact benefit from the favorable prepending performance of a linked list.

Comment: I just did - at 1000 prepending and sorting iterations, the non-reverse method always ran at just 1 millisecond, whereas the reverse method could be as high as 2 milliseconds (but sometimes 1 millisecond, mostly 2 though).  At 100,000 iterations, the non-reverse method is running anywhere from 80 to 86 milliseconds and the reverse method runs at ~60 milliseconds.  It is clear that the reverse method will scale much better but how big will the strings get in use...

Comment: 5000 strings starting at 100 characters (RNG b/t 0 and 9) and prepending 5000 characters (RNG b/t 0 and 9) with a sort after each takes 23-26 seconds to run using the reverse method.  The non-reverse method is still running, currently at 5:30 of CPU time

Comment: Interesting thread! For those familiar with the StringBuilder on source level, do you have any idea why a List of StringBuilders would sort so slowly?  Given mention of linked list of chunks, I'd guess that this may be due to preliminary checks on indexing values.

Comment: As mentioned above, List<LinkedList<char>> sorts quite fast! I never would have guessed that it would sort so much faster than List<StringBuilder>.  Unfortunately, it chews up RAM rapidly too. Given that gene-related algorithms usually require only 4 chars (nucleotides A,T,G,C) or 20 chars (amino acids), I've been experimenting with LinkedList<byte>, but unfortunately it does not save much RAM.  Too much overhead in linkage, etc. ---  Next up: Arrays of bytes, perhaps using reverse sorting.  Or maybe even List<List<byte>>.

Comment: problem with linked list is constant memory allocation and jumping from node to node could be far apart, therefore negating spacial locality.  StringBuilder buffer is contiguous memory.  StringBuilder prepending is very slow because it has to copy each character one index to the right to make space for the new character.  The reverse method avoids this by "appending the prepend" to the end of the string

Comment: updated with test program and results for 2500 string and 2500 prepends

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for the suggestions posted. I checked these, and I have to say that I'm astonished that LinkedList works incredibly well, except for memory usage.

Another surprise is the slow sorting speed of the StringBuilder list. It works quickly as expected for the char insert phase. But the posted benchmarks above reflect what I've found: StringBuilder sorts very slowly for some reason. Painfully slow.

List of strings sorts faster. But counter to intuition, List of LinkedList sorts very fast. I have no idea how navigating a linked list could possibly be faster than simple indexing of a buffer (as in strings and StringBuilder), but it is.  I would never have thought to try LinkedList. Compliments to McAden for the insight!

But unfortunately, LinkedList runs the system out of RAM. So, back to the drawing board.

Comment: have you tried my StringBuilder in reverse algorithm? 2500 strings going from 100 to 2600 characters completes in ~3.5 seconds. I'm about to post my testbed code

Comment: and memory footprint is minimal, most I saw in the 3.5 seconds it ran was 55-60 MB